# tree conflicts for files that have only been touched in trunk

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn, tree-conflict

I am trying to merge a feature branch back into the trunk with Tortoise SVN.

Numerous changes have been made in both, the trunk and the branch, including deletion and movement of folders.

Now I would expect SVN to report a tree conflict when the same file or folder would have been modified in the branch and deleted/moved in the trunk or vice versa.

However I get tree conflicts reported for every single file and folder that has been deleted or moved in either the trunk or the branch, even when this file has not been modified at all on the other side of the merge.

So if I delete a folder in the trunk after the branch has been created and no one touches that folder or any file inside it in the branch at all, then I still get a tree conflict when merging that change.

I even get that conflict in both directions: it doesn't matter if I try to merge the branch back to the trunk or if I try to merge any changes from the trunk into the branch.

My Client is on TortoiseSVN 1.8.11, Subversion 1.8.13 and the repository is on version 1.6.17.

What could cause these strange tree conflicts and how can they be avoided?